# How to 'join' multiple records to multiple records using a UI

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm wondering what the easiest way is to join multiple records to multiple records.

I currently have 3 tables:
Users
Yards
Usersyardslink

The third will be used (I think) to join the records as needed.

The real question is how I achieve this using a UI and populate to the tables using sql..?

I wanted to do this via my currently form for editing users, but I'm not sure how to display yards in a way that will allow for multiple to be chosen and then the correct records being created/deleted in the Usersyardslink table.

Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Since your tables reflect a many-to-many relationship, is it safe to presume that all users can be joined to one or more yards, and that a yard may be owned by more than one user?

Comment: I am currently experimenting with Select2 - a jquery based select box that will allow me to select multiple yards. It's a bit complicated, so if anyone has used this before (or knows a simpler way) give me a shout. Thanks

Comment: @TimMorton yes, that is correct. It's basically for privileges. Each yard can have more than one user who has access, and a user can manage one or more yards.

Comment: Since I don't know your experience level, I would suggest making a solution without AJAX (via jquery) first.  Probably a two-step interface:  1. choose user from a list of users, then 2. choose yard(s) for that user.  The first page could show the user and current yards, but wait until a user is chosen to choose the yards.

Comment: @TimMorton, yes, that sounds like what I've been trying to do. I have my list of users, I go into the user to edit, I can currently select one yard from a dropdown and submit to the database. I can't figure out how to select multiple yards and commit them to the database. Any tutorials I could follow to do something similar?

Comment: Use `<select multiple name="nameAsArray[]" …`. This will send the selections as an array.

Answer (score -1):

You need to run a query and store output in a variable and access with loop

Comment: That won't help to resolve the UI issues

Comment: which ui issue you facing can you share some screenshot?

Comment: I'm not facing any issue, but the OP is.

Comment: what is OP ????

Comment: Original Poster